# Selenium - 'list' object has no attribute 'screenshot_as_png'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to create a file that contains the title, the link and the image of the items on the [ThingVerse](https://www.thingiverse.com/) website.

I was able to observe that when or working with lists some things don't work.

I ended up crashing the part of downloading the photos.

I managed to find them with XPath, but how could I do to download these images?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/PROJETOS/ThingVerse/chromedriver.exe")
driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
driver.get('https://www.thingiverse.com/')

titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='ThingCardHeader__cardNameWrapper--3xgAZ']")

links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='ThingCardBody__cardBodyWrapper--ba5pu']")
links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in links]

images = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='ThingCardBody__cardBodyWrapper--ba5pu']/img")
WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
```

So far the code runs perfectly, but when trying to download the images there is an error

I try:

```
images = [file.write(images.screenshot_as_png) for image in images]
```

Beu file has been discontinued

so I don't know what to do.

Comment: You'll want `image.screenshot_as_png` not `images`. Oh, and you'll probably want to use a different file object for each image.

Comment: It worked. but how can i save this file?

Comment: Your code shows you calling `file.write(...)` but you haven't shown where you've initialized the variable `file`. As I said, you'd need to instantiate a new fileobject for each image in images. This should be covered in all basic tutorials.

Comment: Thanks Justin!!!